# how to get php variables values to display in a jquery loaded form

Tags: php, jquery

title says it all, I have a large form that loads to the web page. this form is to act as an update form so i want to populate it with the old details using PHP session variables so the user doesn't have to fill in the entire form every time they want to change one detail..

in a static web page something like this would work:

```
<tr>
        <td><label for="email">New Email:</label></td>
        <td><input name="email" id="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>" required></td>
    </tr>
```

but i cant seem to get the php variables displaying in the dynamically loaded form.

is there a method for getting around this?

EDIT CLUTTER REMOVED because it didn't help much, simpler version::

how can i get a php variable (local or session - it dosnt matter) eg:

```
$test = "phpContent"
```

to display in a form or div that was loaded from another page after an event like click()

Comment: are you sure $_SESSION['email'] contains a value?

Comment: yea, its set when the user logs in,,

Comment: so if you place the echo statement above it shows some code? Knowing what the current result is whould help.

Comment: @bodovix what does jquery has to do with this? and try to print the $_SESSION['email'] outside the input so you'll be sure that it's there.

Comment: the form is loaded into an empty div using jquery, this way i can use the same div for login,update and register and it flows well no matter what page your on..  but i cant get the php variables to display in the form as default values.

Comment: session['email'] is defiantly set on the page, just cant get it to display in the loaded form.

Comment: @bodovix can you add your code from forms.php and getUserDetails.php. I don't get why do you do `$(window).load('phpConf/getUserDetails.php');`. Also make sure you have session_start() call in forms.php in the top.

Comment: after i couldn't get session variables to load in the form i tryed to do it using regular php variables, hence the second load method, but it didnt work. even php variables defined in the main page wont show in the loaded form, must be missing some logic to do with php and ajax,

Answer (score 0):

Dear bodovix before you call `session_start()` define session name and after write session variables call `session_write_close()`.

```
//example workflow

<?php
session_name( 'fObj' );
session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = 'your email';
session_write_close();
```

Comment: dont think the session variable is the issue, i cant get any php variables, local or session to display in event loaded content (form, div or otherwise dosnt matter which). sorry,  I think putting my code in has over complicated the question

Comment: i assume the content needs to convert as php code, if I'm correct use the below code

Comment: $test = "phpContent"

ob_start();
eval('?>'.$test.'<?php;'); 

$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

Comment: Finally: echo $page;